# swift init not visible in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to create `init` functions in `Swift` and create instances from `Objective-C`. The problem is that I don't see it in `Project-Swift.h` file and I'm not able to find the function while initializing. I have a function defined as below:

```
public init(userId: Int!) {
    self.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.userId = userId
}
```

I even tried putting `@objc(initWithUserId:)` and I keep getting the same error again. Is there anything else I'm missing? How do I get the constructor visible to `Objective-C` code?

I read the below for this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/interactingwithobjective-capis.html

[How to write Init method in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302288/how-to-write-init-method-in-swift)

[How to define optional methods in Swift protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032754/how-to-define-optional-methods-in-swift-protocol)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is that Swift can't bridge optional value types -- `Int` is a value type, so  `Int!` can't be bridged. Optional reference types (i.e., any class) bridge correctly, since they can always be `nil` in Objective-C. Your two options are to make the parameter non-optional, in which case it would be bridged to ObjC as an `int` or `NSInteger`:

```
// Swift
public init(userId: Int) {
    self.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.userId = userId
}

// ObjC
MyClass *instance = [[MyClass alloc] initWithUserId: 10];
```

Or use an optional `NSNumber?`, since that can be bridged as an optional value:

```
// Swift
public init(userId: NSNumber?) {
    self.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.userId = userId?.integerValue
}

// ObjC
MyClass *instance = [[MyClass alloc] initWithUserId: @10];    // note the @-literal
```

Note, however, you're not actually treating the parameter like an optional - unless `self.userId` is also an optional you're setting yourself up for potential runtime crashes this way.

Answer (score 11):

use this one:

```
var index: NSInteger!

@objc convenience init(index: NSInteger) {
    self.init()

    self.index = index
}
```