# Swift init is not visible from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm taking as base this thread:

[swift init not visible in objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470771/swift-init-not-visible-in-objective-c)

And I have the next class:

**TokenModel.swift**

```
public class TokenModel: NSObject, NSCoding, Codable {

    required public init(usuario:String?, tokenSesion:String?, nombreCompleto:String?, cliente:String?, paises:[PaisModel]?) {
        Usuario = usuario
        TokenSesion = tokenSesion
        NombreCompleto = nombreCompleto
        Cliente = cliente
        Paises = paises
    }

    public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        Usuario = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Usuario") as? String
        TokenSesion = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "TokenSesion") as? String
        NombreCompleto = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "NombreCompleto") as? String
        Cliente = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Cliente") as? String
        Paises = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Paises") as? [PaisModel]
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(Usuario, forKey: "Usuario")
        aCoder.encode(TokenSesion, forKey: "TokenSesion")
        aCoder.encode(NombreCompleto, forKey: "NombreCompleto")
        aCoder.encode(Cliente, forKey: "Cliente")
        aCoder.encode(Paises, forKey: "Paises")
    }

    public var Usuario:String?
    public var TokenSesion:String?
    public var NombreCompleto:String?
    public var Cliente:String?
    public var Paises:[PaisModel]?
}
```

**MyObjective.m**

`TokenModel * tm =  [[TokenModel alloc] init];`

> There no methods (except aDecoder) are displayed

There, I have defined a simple method, who are implemented on `Swift`.
But, at the moment to use it on my `Objective-C` project, the only visible method is `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)`.

What other things I tried?

- I tried creating a `required public init()` (without parameters).
- Deleting the `aDecoder`.
- Creating a method `init(demo:NSString)`

But, those methods are not appearing on my `Objective C` class.

Does anyone know how I can import my custom init using `Objective-C`?

Comment: try **@objcMembers class TokenModel:NSObject, NSCoding, Codable**

Comment: add @objc to infront of class definition and initializer definition

Comment: Also the param `PaisModel` should be available in obj-c as well.

Comment: @Sh_Khan i tried, but is still not working. Is my objective c code right?

Comment: Please show declaration for PaisModel.

Comment: Did you find the answer? If yes, please share.