# Expected identifier in function declaration - Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert over my Objective-C to Swift - a little confused on the error here and how to take care of it.  I've been reading through the documentation but still confused - this was generated from a converter.  Anyone have any ideas?

```
Objective-C
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (!self)
        return nil;

     self.cmRequestsQuery = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
     self.cmQueryIsRuning = NO;
     self.requestCounter = 0;
     self.serverOfflineOrBadResponse = NO;
     self.userWasLoggedIn = NO;
     self.needToSendPushNotiToken = NO;
     self.noInternetConection = NO;
     self.needToUpdateToken = NO;

    [[reqOperationManager sharedManager] setDelegate:self];

    return self;
}


Swift
func init() -> AnyObject {
    self = super()
    if !self {
        return nil
    }
    self.cmRequestsQuery = NSMutableArray(capacity: 5)
    self.cmQueryIsRuning = false
    self.requestCounter = 0
    self.serverOfflineOrBadResponse = false
    self.userWasLoggedIn = false
    self.needToSendPushNotiToken = false
    self.noInternetConection = false
    self.needToUpdateToken = false
    reqOperationManager.sharedManager().setDelegate(self)
    return self
}
```

Comment: That took care of one issue, it still complains at `func init() -> AnyObject {` with "Expected identifier in function declaration.  Removing the "func" part then brings the error "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'.  I believe it is from the AnyObject aspect.

Comment: See [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302288/how-to-write-init-method-in-swift)

Answer (score 27):

In Swift `init` methods have no `func` keyword and no return value and the point to call super is different.

```
init() {
```

First initialize all instance variables.

```
self.cmRequestsQuery = NSMutableArray(capacity: 5)
self.cmQueryIsRuning = false
self.requestCounter = 0
self.serverOfflineOrBadResponse = false
self.userWasLoggedIn = false
self.needToSendPushNotiToken = false
self.noInternetConection = false
self.needToUpdateToken = false
```

Then call super – if required – to get the instance.

```
super.init()
```

Then call the methods which use `self`

```
reqOperationManager.sharedManager().setDelegate(self)
```

That's it.

```
}
```

In some cases you have to add the `override` keyword before `init()`.

For more details please read the chapter about Initialization in the Swift Language Guide. It's worth it.

Comment: The "Initialization in the Swift Language Guide" mentioned at the end of the answer:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because I was trying to import the swift header (import "ProjectName-swift.h") in my swift class.