# Check if variable is nil from UICollectionViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have got this `UICollectionViewcell`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

    if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post {
        if(CurrentPost.PostImage == nil) {
            print(CurrentPost.PostText)
        }
    }

    return cell
}

class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        designCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let postImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return v
    }()

    func designCell() {
        addSubview(postImage)

        if (postImage.image == nil) {
            print("ss")
        }

        cellConstraints()
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is to check is at `posts[indexPath.row]` the `PostImage` is nil or not. If it is nil then at `PostCell` I want to print "ss", otherwise I want to set `postImage`'s image to `PostImage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your cell:

```
func passImage(imageToSet: UIImage?){
    if let image = imageToSet{
        //Do whatever you want
    }else{
        print("ss")
    }
}
```

In your VC

```
if let CurrentPost = posts[indexPath.row] as? Post{
    cell.passImage(imageToSet: CurrentPost.PostImage)
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work because passImage is getting called after the class

Comment: It should work no matter when you initialize your class.

Comment: Oh right it did work,i thought that it won't because it comes after the init.Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1):

```
class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var postImg: UIImage!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        designCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, img: UIImage) {
        self.postImg = img
        designCell()
    }

    let postImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        v.image = postImg
        return v
    }()
    func getImage(img: UIImage) {
        self.postImg = img
    }
    func designCell(){

        addSubview(postImage)
        if(postImage.image == nil){
            print("ss")
        }
        cellConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need it in `PostCell` so i can change constraints and stuff

Comment: Oh, for that you will have to create a method to pass your image into the PostCell class. Maybe you should add another parameter in init method for taking an uiimage object and then check that uiimage object.

Comment: adding another parameter gives me an error: `Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass`

Comment: `getImage` gets called after the class is called,so it automatically gives it a value of nil`

Comment: you should try to create a custom init and call self.init inside that function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302288/how-to-write-init-method-in-swift

Comment: i tried to create my own initializer like this: `convenience init(frame: CGRect,image:UIImage?) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        designCell()
    }
    ` but it gave me an error saying that `self.init(frame: frame)` should be `self.init(coder: frame)` then another error saying that coder and frame are different things

Answer (score 1):

First create two different methods for constraint adjustment with respect to image availability.

```
class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        designCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    let postImage: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return v
    }()
    func designCell(){

        addSubview(postImage)
        if(postImage.image == nil){
            print("ss")
        }
    }

    func cellConstraintForImageWithoutText(){
         //Change your constraint if data have image but doesn't have text
    }
    func cellConstraintForImageWithText(){
         //Change your constraint if data have image as well as text
    }
    func cellConstraintForNoImageWithoutText(){
         //Change your constraint if data neither have image nor have text
    }
    func cellConstraintForNoImageWithText(){
         //Change your constraint if data doesn't have image but have text
    }
}
```

Now just check if image is nil then call NoImage method else call other method.

```
let postText = CurrentPost.text

if let img = CurrentPost.PostImage {
    if txt = postText {
        cell.cellConstraintForImageWithText()             
    }else {
        cell.cellConstraintForImageWithoutText()            
    }
}
else {
    if txt = postText {
        cell.cellConstraintForNoImageWithText()             
    }else {
        cell.cellConstraintForNoImageWithoutText()            
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish there was a shorter way.There are five possibilities: with image and with text,without image with text,without image without text,with image without text

Comment: Logically there is only four possible scenario not five

Comment: When i scroll back every function is being called so it messes up